# How can you manually toggle a Foundation 5 dropdown in javascript (inside an emberjs app)?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, zurb-foundation

I am having issues getting a dropdown to be bound properly in an ember js app because I have `action` handlers on click inside of the list and the foundation events are conflicting.

**Template name:**

```
<a data-dropdown="groupDrop" id="groupDropdownLink" class="button radius tiny success dropdown">
   Move Selected To Group ({{selectedCount}})
</a>
<br>
<ul id="groupDrop" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
  {{#each eventGroups}}
    <li {{action 'moveToGroup' this}}><a>{{name}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

When I run $(document).foundation() it overrides the action handlers, and when I remove that it doesn't trigger the dropdown.

What I think I need to do is add some action handler to the `a` tag and then have it open up the dropdown, so I can not use the foundation handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you need to use to trigger the dropdown is `Foundation.libs.dropdown.toggle`

You pass in a jQuery object of the dropdown link to toggle it

You can solve it like this:

template:

```
<a data-dropdown="groupDrop" {{action 'showDropdown'}} id="groupDropdownLink" class="button radius tiny success dropdown">
   Move Selected To Group ({{selectedCount}})
</a>
<br>
<ul id="groupDrop" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
  {{#each eventGroups}}
    <li {{action 'moveToGroup' this}}><a>{{name}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

controller:

```
Ea.GroupGuestsController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  actions:

    showDropdown: ->
      Foundation.libs.dropdown.toggle($('#groupDropdownLink'))
```

Comment: This works well to show the dropdown, but the dropdown doesn't hide itself (as is the usual behaviour with Foundation dropdowns) when I click outside the dropdown contents. Any idea what the cause could be? The only way to hide it again is to press the toggle again, which isn't ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've had plenty of problems like that when having to manually trigger foundation js actions unfortunately.. I'd love if someone had a real way to do this without these problems

Comment: In my case, the issue was loading Foundation at the wrong time. I've tried several different methods, but the one that finally worked was initializing it in App.ApplicationView's "didInsertElement" method.