# Foundation 5 Dropdown button not working in nested table row

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js, zurb-foundation-5

Dropdown button not working if the dropdown button is inside a nested table row.

Please refer to this example in jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yesaguwoli/edit?html,output

- Click on Header 1 to show an expanded table row.
- Then, click on **Dropdown Button 1**. The dropdown menu **does not appear** after the button is clicked.
- Click on Header 2 to show an expanded table row.
- Then, click on **+** button. The dropdown menu **does not appear** after the button is clicked.

However, if you the dropdown button is located in the table row itself, the dropdown button will work fine in both places, (ie. in the table row and in the nested table row)

Refer to this example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mozudezewo/edit?html,css,js,output

- Click on **Dropdown Button 1**. The dropdown menu **appears** after the button is clicked.
- Click on Header 2 to show an expanded table row.
- Then, click on **+** button. The dropdown menu **appears** after the button is clicked.

I'm not sure why the dropdown button is behaving in such a way. Any help to resolve this issue is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have taken your working example, and wrapped it in the same `{{if}}` statements as your broken example (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bubeveyapo/1/edit?html,output) and it no longer works.

This is because you are initializing the `foundation` dropdowns on the `didInsertElement` hook of the `App.ApplicationView`.

The problem is that when you initialize foundation, there is no `.dropdown` in the DOM at the time the `App.ApplicationView` is inserted as they are hidden by the `{{if}}` statements. These `{{if}}` tags actually remove and insert the HTML blobs in the DOM.

So what you need to do is find a way of knowing when the dropdown has been inserted and re-initialize foundation.

Foundation has a way of handling re-initialization with `$(document).foundation('dropdown', 'reflow');` which will check the DOM again for anything foundation'ey and re-apply the javascript for it.

[This JSbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xitehehuqi/edit?html,js,output) has re-initialized foundation on the `toggleDetails` action, as that's when the buttons are being inserted.

Really you should look into not relying on foundation to show hide your dropdowns and look at adding `{{action}}` hooks on them and manually managing the show/hide. This has been answered here on SO so take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909350/how-can-you-manually-toggle-a-foundation-5-dropdown-in-javascript-inside-an-emb).

Comment: Thank you, @PhilHauser for your reply and explanation on what is the problem with my code. Regarding the updated [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nebemunexe/1/edit?html,js,output) you shared, the dropdown menu seems to only work on the dropdown button for  `Header 2`. But, after you click on the dropdown button on `Header 2`, the dropdown menu on `Header 1` will work as well.

Comment: As for the SO question, I did try it out on my code and is working fine after adding `{{action}}` hooks to manually toggle the dropdown menu show/hide. However, the dropdown menu does not auto close by itself using this method. Currently, I'm looking for ways to manually close the dropdown menu.

Comment: With regards to the jsbin I shared, you're correct that the 1st dropdown doesn't work, this is because I was re-initializing foundation before the button was in the dom. I've [updated](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xitehehuqi/edit?html,js,output) it with a disgusting setTimeout to illustrate the point. If you post anther JSbin with the new `{{action}}` hook way I can take a look.